# How do I correct the "Object Expected" Error when it inloves var queryStringVals = $().SPServices.SPGetQueryString();?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Hi have been getting an error stating.. Object Expected for these 2 lines of code:

```
function AsyncSave(send) {

//alert ('In CustomSave');   
var drp =     document.getElementById("Sample_sample_DropDownChoice");
var drpValue = drp.options[drp.selectedIndex].value;

var varAnalysis = getTagFromIdentifierAndTitle("textarea","TextField","Principal Comments");
var varAnalysisTextBoxID = RTE_GetEditorDocument(varAnalysis.id);
var varAnalysisText = varAnalysisTextBoxID.body.innerText;  

alert ('Save N Send');
alert (drpValue);
alert (varAnalysisText);
```

Error Happens when it gets to the line below

```
var queryStringVals = $().SPServices.SPGetQueryString();
var itemID = queryStringVals["itemID"];
```

What could be the problem.. should I be running different up to date SPServices.. this is 2010 btw.

The goal is to take the values entered, save them, and update them (send) to another form/List.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint 2010 has a built-in JavaScript method for retrieving values from the query string. Try using the following:

```
var itemID = GetUrlKeyValue("itemID");
```

That's assuming the URL of the page on which the script is running actually has a query string parameter of "itemID"

Comment: Thanks! this definitely helped me grab the ID I was looking for. Would this change prevent me from using $().SPServices(   ... to continue to finish completing my task?

Comment: It shouldn't prevent you from using SPServices, but since SPServices was giving you errors before, there may be something wrong with how it's being referenced.